# SAS looping over variable list to count unique values

Tags: sas

I am not quite familiar with SAS logic and don't know which steps to use for my task. Basically I want to calculate the ratio between number of unique records and number of records (unique ratio) to determine whether a variable is discrete, or continuous. The dataset contains 700+ variables and 5M records, so using proc freq will likely crash.

Here is my proprosed steps:

1. Sample 100000 from the dataset
2. Calculate the 'unique ratio' for each column in the sample

Repeat step 1 and step 2 for N times, say 50 times. We would have final data set like:

```
  Var_name  Sample_Number  Unique_ratio
    Var_1       1               0.58
     ....        .....           .....
```

Then for each variable calculate the average unique ratio across all N samples.

I can easily do this in python or R. But it is just quite painful to translate that into SAS. Could any SAS expert give me some advices?

Comment: Are the variables numeric or char or a mix?

Comment: It is a mix of char and numeric :)

Comment: Useful page here. http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Cardinality_Ratio. I wonder if you might have enough memory for a hash approach?  Would your continuous variables have millions of different values or perhaps only thousands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the NLEVELS statistic from PROC FREQ.  Here is an example using SASHELP.CLASS dataset that has a mix of numeric and character variables. Note that I am using the NOBS option on an unexecuted SET statement to get the total number of observations.  If your input is a view then you might need to count the number of observations some other way.

```
proc freq nlevels data=sashelp.class ;
  ods output nlevels=nlevels;
  tables _all_ / noprint ;
run;
data want ;
  if 0 then set sashelp.class(drop=_all_) nobs=nobs ;
  set nlevels;
  total=nobs;
  unique_ratio = nlevels/total ;
run;
proc print; run;
```

If you really do have a large number of unique values then you might have to run this on just a random subset of the data.  PROC FREQ should be able to handle 10,000 observations of 700 variables, even if all of them are unique.

Comment: Note the question claims that "Running PROC FREQ is likely to crash".  I make no particular judgement about the veracity thereof.

Comment: The idea in the original post of using a sample of 10,000 observations will work.  Even when all 700+ variables are unique SAS can handle 700*10,000 unique values.

Comment: I understand (and agree) - just thought it was worth mentioning in the answer, since you're explicitly going against something the question asked.

Comment: Thank you both! The procedure works on a sample with 100,000 observations. I just need to set a loop to calculate unique_ratio for multiple random samples

Comment: @user2517984 I suggest reading David Cassell's 'Don't be Loopy' on how to do that efficiently.

Answer (score 1):

```
 proc sql;
    create table need as
    select Distinct count(*) as unique_records,count(xxx)as number_of_rec
    from have;`enter code here`

    quit;

    data need1;
    set need;
    ratio=(unique_records/number_of_rec)*100;
    run;
```

Comment: Please note that text that is not in code should not be indented into a code block; it should be in complete English words/sentences ("You" not "u" etc.); and it should address the answer.  "I'm not sure if this will work" isn't really useful unless you describe the assumptions you're making which you're not sure about.

Comment: Thank you Joe for Suggestions.